# Find the distance between a surface and a plane

Tags: calculus

Hi guys I have another question thats giving me a hard time, can someone please help me out with it ?

I need to find the distance between a surface and a plane. I know that it has to be something with lagrange multipliers but i dont really know how to define the functions for it.

the surface is
$$ 
\{(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2=z \}
$$
and the plane
$$
-2x-2y+z=7
$$

thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure those equations are right?  Because as they stand, the distance is zero...

Comment: yes I'm sure. how did you solve it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you understand that the distance will be zero if the surface and plane intersect anywhere, right?

Comment: yes. but i don't understand how to know if the distance is 0 if i couldn't see it in the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write this as an answer:

First try roughly sketching the surfaces, to see what's going on.  You should immediately realise that the distance is zero, as I gave away in my comment.  It is then straightforward algebra to prove that this is true.

Comment: first, thanks. second: if it wasn't zero, how would i solve it?